# Displaying the sum of 'output'

Tags: python, sum

Trying to diplay the integer total of my input/samples.

This is a learning curve for me however i feel if the tools wook above then it should be able to show output too.

I've tried the print function but as i anticipated it only printed 'output.

```
>>> input = [71,10,1001,332]
>>> samples = [8]
>>> output = (sum(input)/sum(samples))
>>> sum(output)
```

I am looking for the output to show the calculated result. I understand this would be simple and i have been looking on here for similar situations but contexts are so different it didnt help.

Comment: try `print(output)` on the last line instead

Comment: So i did use the print(output) function first time but only got 'output'. I see what i did wrong thank you for confirming what i needed to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) in Python.

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

If you are using [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) mean your input to the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a iterable  object. Most probably you get following error.

```sh
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Isn't it? No worries, try bellow solutions.

```py
>>> output
176.75
>>> print(output)
176.75
>>> sum([output])
176.75
```

Comment: That is the error i got. Thanks alot for your help, this is the clarification i needed.

Comment: You're welcome @Stiglix, if it's working please make this answer as the accepted one.